# RxCocoa - Why doesn't PublishRelay have an asDriver() method?

Tags: ios, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

On RxCocoa I was wondering why the PublishRelay doesn't have an asDriver() method like the BehaviorRelay ? Currently if I want to convert the publishRelay into a Driver, I have to specify what to return in case of error which seems weird given that the relays can't generate errors...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Those two versions of `...Relay` are used to model different concepts:

- `BehaviorRelay` represents **State**
- `PublishRelay` represents **Events**

It makes sense to replay **State**, hence `BehaviorRelay` replays its latest value.

It makes less (no?) sense to replay **Events**, hence `PublishRelay` does not replay its latest value.

With this in mind, it makes sens for a `BehaviorRelay` to be transformable to [`Driver`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/Traits/Driver/Driver.swift), as a driver drives the application using **State**. The sharing strategy for `BehaviorRelay` and `Driver` is to share side effects **and replay the latest value** while at least one observable is connected.

A `PublishRelay` is better represented by a [`Signal`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/Traits/Signal/Signal.swift), so you probably could use a `Signal` to emit to. The sharing strategy in this case is will **not** replay the latest value, but still share the side effects while at least one observable is connected.

(I build this answer using this [great comment](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/pull/1769#issuecomment-429733057) from @freak4pc on RxSwift's repository)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comment. You're right. I had missed the part where the Driver was meant to replay the last event ! I makes more sense now :)

Answer (score 7):

If someone need a simple example:

```
publishRelay
            .asDriver(onErrorDriveWith: Driver.empty())
            .drive(onNext: { value in

            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```